# How to do stream processing with Redpanda?

Tags: apache-kafka, stream-processing, redpanda

Redpanda seems easy to work with, but how would one process streams in real-time?

We have a few thousand IoT devices that send us data every second. We would like to get the running average of the data from the last hour for each of the devices. Can the built-in WebAssembly stuff be used for this, or do we need something like Materialize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that it is marketed as "Kafka Compatible," any Kafka library should work with RedPanda, including Kafka Streams, KSQL, Apache Spark, Flink, Storm, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, folks. Since it hasn't been mentioned I'm going to add my own answer as well here.

We ended up using [Bytewax](https://bytewax.io/).

It worked great with our existing Kubernetes setup. It supports stateful operations and scales horizontally into multiple pods if needed. It's pretty performant (1), and since it's basically just a python program it can be customized to read and write to whatever you want.

(1) The Bytewax pod actually uses less CPU than our KafkaJS pod, which just stores all messages to a DB.

Answer (score 0):

Here's more information about stream processors that work with Redpanda.
https://redpanda.com/blog/kafka-stream-processors